# Spring MongoDB - Array objects come over null

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb

I have a mongo collection that has an embedded array of ObjectId's, so the general format is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123abc..."),
    "Active" : [ 
        {
            "Id" : ObjectId("123abc...")
        }, 
        {
            "Id" : ObjectId("123abc...")
        }, 
        ...,
        {
            "Id" : ObjectId("123abc...")
        }
    ],
    "field1" : "blah blah",
    "field2" : "blah blah",
    "field3" : "blah blah",
    "field4" : "blah blah"
    "field5" : ObjectId("123abc...")
}
```

My Java class is pretty simple:

```
@Document(collection="MyCollection")
public class MyCollection {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String field1;
    ...
    private ObjectId field5;
    @Field("Active")
    private List<Active> active;

    // Getters & Setters here

   public static class Active {
    @Field("Id")
    private ObjectId id;

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
  }
}
```

When I do the query, everything comes over correctly but the "Active" field. If there are 18 entries in that array, I will get a List of size 18, but the 18 entries of Active.class are all null - so it gets that it's a List, it just never pulls over the ObjectId values within the active array.

I'm using Spring and the Spring mongo driver.

**EDIT**: If I use the mongo-java-driver and query this way:

```
    DB database = mongoClient.getDB("myDB");
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("MyCollection");

    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("123abc..."));
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    DBObject jo = cursor.one();
```

It works and I get the entire document that I'm looking for - so I assume there is a way to do this in the Spring manner?

Answer (score 0):

Before I was using these versions in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

By updating to one version newer for each:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I was able to solve this problem. So now when I do my query:

```
        return Arrays.asList(mongoTemplate.findById(new ObjectId("123abc..."), Foo.class));
```

The array of ObjectId's come back intact (where as before I would get an array of the correct size - so it knew there were 18 of them - but it was an array of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Why did not you use annotation @Id like in MyCollection class?

```
public static class Active {
 @Id
 private ObjectId id;

}
```